# Impact of changing existing constraint name in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have few constraint_name which start with SYS_Cn (e.g.: SYS_C00323441). I need to alter it and rename with a proper naming convention.

But I am concerned whether altering of constraint name will have any impact on the DB?

Will it make make any objects invalid?

Or what are the possible scenarios it could generate?

Kindly provide me with the info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you're hard coding somewhere by constraint name, i don't see any problem in renaming the constraint name.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso I have not used any hardcorded constraint_name in DB.
But I am concerned regrading invalid objects, since by altering tables to add/drop column to a table make other dependent objects invalid and hence it need recompile.

Syntax to change constraint name: alter table <table_name> rename constraint <old_constraint_name> to <new_constraint_name>; 
By altering table to rename its constraint_name will not make any objects invalid?